# Dropdown selection list to filter from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a list of events in a mysql database that I want the user to be able to filter by location using a drop-down list. I've managed to get the drop down box sorted and the table to display the data but choosing a selection at the moment does nothing.

On a separate issue, I have multiple locations of the same value so the same locations are appearing multiple times in the drop down menu... would be good to sort this out, but getting it working first is priority!

this is my code (I wasn't sure how much of it to paste in):

```
<?php require_once('Connections/united_hosting.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
$theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
}

$theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

switch ($theType) {
case "text":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;    
case "long":
case "int":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "double":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "date":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
case "defined":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
  break;
}
return $theValue;
}
}

$maxRows_rs_blog = 3;
$pageNum_rs_blog = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_rs_blog'])) {
$pageNum_rs_blog = $_GET['pageNum_rs_blog'];
}
$startRow_rs_blog = $pageNum_rs_blog * $maxRows_rs_blog;

mysql_select_db($database_united_hosting, $united_hosting);
$query_rs_blog = "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%D %M %Y') AS format_date FROM blog_posts ORDER BY `date` DESC";
$query_limit_rs_blog = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_rs_blog, $startRow_rs_blog, $maxRows_rs_blog);
$rs_blog = mysql_query($query_limit_rs_blog, $united_hosting) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rs_blog = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_blog);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_rs_blog'])) {
$totalRows_rs_blog = $_GET['totalRows_rs_blog'];
} else {
$all_rs_blog = mysql_query($query_rs_blog);
$totalRows_rs_blog = mysql_num_rows($all_rs_blog);
}
$totalPages_rs_blog = ceil($totalRows_rs_blog/$maxRows_rs_blog)-1;
$query_rs_blog = "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%D %M %Y')AS format_date FROM blog_posts ORDER BY `date` DESC";
$rs_blog = mysql_query($query_rs_blog, $united_hosting) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rs_blog = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_blog);
$totalRows_rs_blog = mysql_num_rows($rs_blog);

mysql_select_db($database_united_hosting, $united_hosting);
$query_rs_news = "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date_posted, '%D %M %Y')AS format_date FROM news_item ORDER BY date_posted DESC";
$rs_news = mysql_query($query_rs_news, $united_hosting) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rs_news = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_news);
$totalRows_rs_news = mysql_num_rows($rs_news);

mysql_select_db($database_united_hosting, $united_hosting);
$query_rs_events = "SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY `date` ASC";
$rs_events = mysql_query($query_rs_events, $united_hosting) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rs_events = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_events);
$totalRows_rs_events = mysql_num_rows($rs_events);

$colname_rs_location = "-1";
if (isset($_POST['location'])) {
$colname_rs_location = $_POST['location'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_united_hosting, $united_hosting);
$query_rs_location = sprintf("SELECT location FROM events WHERE location = %s ORDER BY `date` ASC", GetSQLValueString($colname_rs_location, "text"));
$rs_location = mysql_query($query_rs_location, $united_hosting) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rs_location = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_location);
$totalRows_rs_location = mysql_num_rows($rs_location);
?>


<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
<p>
<label for="select">Select:</label>
<select name="select" id="select">
  <?php
do {  
?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row_rs_events['location']?>"<?php if (!(strcmp($row_rs_events['location'], $_POST['']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>><?php echo $row_rs_events['location']?></option>
  <?php
} while ($row_rs_events = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_events));
$rows = mysql_num_rows($rs_events);
if($rows > 0) {
  mysql_data_seek($rs_events, 0);
  $row_rs_events = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_events);
}
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</p>
<table width="600" border="1">
<tr>
  <th scope="col">location</th>
  <th scope="col">venue</th>
  <th scope="col">date</th>
  <th scope="col">tickets</th>
</tr>
<?php do { ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row_rs_events['location']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_rs_events['venue_name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_rs_events['date']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_rs_events['tickets_remaining']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } while ($row_rs_events = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_events)); ?>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($rs_blog);

mysql_free_result($rs_events);

mysql_free_result($rs_location);
?>
```

Comment: "I have multiple locations of the same value so the same locations are appearing multiple times in the drop down menu", add DISTINCT after the SELECT in your sql query that retrieves the locations.

Comment: About the select not doing anything, what do you mean by that? Does that mean that when you choose something it out of the dropbox it doesn't display what you clicked? If that is the case please check you r html syntax via right clicking the dropbox then Inspect Element, or if that is not available, just view the source and see if the dropbox html is correct

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT location FROM events WHERE location = %s ORDER BY `date` ASC
```

The **DISTINCT** keyword will allow you to get a result set with only one of each location.

```
if (isset($_POST['location'])) {
    $colname_rs_location = $_POST['location'];
}
```

Ensure the scipt sending POST data to this script has an input field with a name of location. Currently the form in the code provided uses the name select.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can't seem to get the DISTINCT bit working, am sure I remember using this before though so will check again. Is this right for renaming the form?...
    <input type="submit" name="location" id="submit" value="Submit">